# Replace a subarray with an array containing the subarray

Tags: php, arrays, json

How to convert this object to array without nesting inside. Just need to convert create links array and push the leftSection --> links object in it.

```
"leftSection": {
   "contentHtml": {
     "value": {
       "de": "Vel ut dicta dolore tractatos"
     }
   },
   "links": {
     "link": {
       "title_de": "Demo Link",
       "linkMode": "external",
     }
   }
 }
```

Output should be like below.

```
 "leftSection": {
    "contentHtml": {
      "value": {
        "de": "Vel ut dicta dolore tractatos"
      }
    },
    "links": [ 
      {
      "link": {
        "title_de": "Demo Link",
        "linkMode": "external",
      }
    }
   ]
  }
```

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck? We're happy to help people _where necessary_ but (as volunteers) we do expect that you make a reasonable effort to try and solve it first, and demonstrate what you've researched and attempted, and where you are having a problem specifically. See also [ask]

Comment: I got struck where i need to convert the above object to array. I'm new to PHP where i tried json_decode() function to solve but I'm worried how to do correctly

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show the code you've got so far, then we at least don't have to repeat work that you've already done

Comment: P.S. If we're talking about JSON, then `[
    "contentHtml"` isn't valid JSON. JSON arrays can't contain property names. So _maybe_ the reason you're stuck is actually because you're aiming to create something which is impossible.

Comment: I need to restructure like array of objects. So now "leftSection": {} is an object but i need "leftSection": [] and the "contentHtml": {} and "links": {} object inside it

Comment: Json arrays cannot contain keys, please figure out what you need.

Comment: @NeonH you don't seem to have understood what I wrote. JSON arrays cannot contained named keys/properties. So `"leftSection": []` is not possible unless you also alter what you want inside it.

Comment: `an array of objects`...so maybe you actually want `{
    "leftSection": [
        {
            "contentHtml": {
                "value": {
                    "de": "Vel ut dicta dolore tractatos"
                }
            },
            "links": {
                "link": {
                    "title_de": "Demo Link",
                    "linkMode": "external"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}` ?? P.S. You can always validate any JSON you've created at sites like https://jsonlint.com to check if it's actually possible.

Comment: I'm editing the question. Give me some time. I got your point

Comment: Or maybe you want `{
    "leftSection": [
        {
            "value": {
                "de": "Vel ut dicta dolore tractatos"
            }
        },
        {
            "link": {
                "title_de": "Demo Link",
                "linkMode": "external"
            }
        }
    ]
}` - without the named keys? It's a bit unclear. Note that while PHP _can_ have associative arrays (i.e. arrays with named instead of (impliclity) numbered keys), JSON cannot - they are always represented as objects instead.

Comment: I updated the question now. 

```
"leftSection": {
    "contentHtml": {
      "value": {
        "de": "Vel ut dicta dolore tractatos"
      }
    },
    "links": [ 
      {
      "link": {
        "title_de": "Demo Link",
        "linkMode": "external",
      }
    }
   ]
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. Makes more sense. The solution is quite simple - I added an answer, below

Comment: How to do if the links array has more than one link. Need to loop through index right instead hardcoding index

Comment: in your original JSON, links is an object so it's not an array, so your question doesn't make sense. The most it could have is multiple _properties_ with different names. I don't know if something like `"links": {
     "link": {
       "title_de": "Demo Link",
       "linkMode": "external",
     }, "link2" { "title_de": "Demo Link 2", "linkMode": "internal" }
   }` is what you mean? If not, please show an example of what you do mean.

Comment: "links": [
      {
        "title_de": "Demo Link",
        "linkMode": "external",
        "linkTextColor": "",
        "hasTextDecoration": false
      },
      {
        "title_de": "Demo Link",
        "linkMode": "external",
        "linkTextColor": "",
        "hasTextDecoration": false
      }
    ]

like this

Comment: So you're telling me that `links` might _already_ contain an array, when you receive the original JSON? But sometimes it's only an object? Rather than just pasting code into comments without explanation, please [edit] your question to add the example _and_ a clear description of the scenario. Then we can reliably write code to deal with it. Also, in future, please be sure to cover all the possiblities _before_ people start writing answers, so as to save time and effort! Thanks

Comment: `$data['leftSection']["links"] = [$data['leftSection']["links"]];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, simply decode the JSON, set the "links" property as a new array containing the previous content of links (i.e. the  object) in the first index, and then re-encode as JSON:

```
<?php

$jsonString = '{
  "leftSection": {
    "contentHtml": {
      "value": {
        "de": "Vel ut dicta dolore tractatos"
      }
    },
    "links": {
      "link": {
        "title_de": "Demo Link",
        "linkMode": "external"
      }
    }
  }
}';


// Decode JSON to an associative array
$data = json_decode($jsonString, true);

// Wrap the links object in an array
$data['leftSection']["links"] = array(0 => $data['leftSection']["links"]);

// re-encode to JSON
$jsonString = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
echo $jsonString;
```

Live demo: https://3v4l.org/vLSNq